# ImportError: install/liboofem.so: undefined symbol: gc

Tags: python, c

when I was going to link the oofem and yade, i have already linked liboofem to current work directory use follow command

> ln -s current/work/directory/liboofem.so oofem/build/directory/liboofem.so

however, when I was going to make the file, in a python scripts, the command “import liboofem”, then raise the

> ImportError: install/liboofem.so: undefined symbol: gc

Answer (score 0):

`cmake -DUSE_OOFEG="ON" -DUSE_PYTHON_BINDINGS="ON" -DCKIT_DIR="/home/shguan/oofem/Ckit" -DELIXIR_DIR="/home/shguan/oofem/Elixir" ../oofem-2.5`

should be replaced by

`cmake -DUSE_PYTHON_BINDINGS="ON" -DCKIT_DIR="/home/shguan/oofem/Ckit" -DELIXIR_DIR="/home/shguan/oofem/Elixir" ../oofem-2.5`

that is to say the oofeg make this error!